# Improve localStorage performance in iPhone4 devices (iOS7)

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am using phonegap for my one of the applications and it heavily depends on localStorage. I have written all my code using traditional getItem and setItem of JS like below

```
 localStorage.setItem(key, val)
```

and

```
 localStorage.getItem(key)
```

It works well in Android but in iPhone4 running with iOS7 it will be terribly slow. How can I improve the performance of localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a small wrapper for localStorage like below and now it is working like a charm, please use it if anybody is interested and please let me know if any better solutions available.

```
var LStorage = (function () {
    function LStorage() {
        this.localStorage = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage));
    }
    LStorage.prototype.setItem = function (key, val) {
        this.localStorage[key] = val;
        localStorage.setItem(key, val);
    };
    LStorage.prototype.getItem = function (key, undef) {
        var val = this.localStorage[key];
        return val;
    };
    LStorage.prototype.removeItem = function (key) {
        delete this.localStorage[key];
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
        return true;
    };
    return LStorage;
})();
```

Thanks.